# What's the difference between using 3.7v and 9v as phantom for electret mic?

Tags: audio, lipo, microphone

I'd like to pass from a mic/filter/amp circuit with the LM386 and powered by a 9v battery in single supply to a 3.7v equivalent using the PAM8403. In hi-fi audio the phantom DC is 48v. Is there any downside in using a voltage as low as 3.7?

Comment: It won't run. Like trying to run a 48V circuit with 3.7V.

Comment: there's simply different microphones with different supply voltage requirements and different current limiting inside. 9V would most definitely destroy my desk electret. Other mics won't do with less. Can't plug a professional 48V one into 9V and expect it to work, either.

Comment: 48V isn't used for electret mics, and it would kill them. 3.7V will be fine. In hi-fi audio you won't find either LM386 or PAM8403 so the mic requirements aren't relevant. (You might need an opamp gain stage between mic and PAM8403 though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electret phantom power only drives the Idss of a JFET with a crystal ceramic mic. such that the gain and DC rise with the pullup resistor.  So it is ~ 1mA.  The expected max input of the PAM8403 on  5V at max gain of 24dB (~21) supply is +/-0.5V  which you could get by shouting into it.  So it is not the "Line Levels" expected from PAM8403 and needs a 10x gain AC coupled.

Pro Audio Phantom power is another beast with moving-coil and amplifier for high quality. But some run on 3V and 1mA like Sony.

Take these mics, which all use 48 volts. A Sennheiser MKH800 draws 3.0 mA, a Neumann U87 draws .8 mA, while a Shure KSM 32 draws 4.6 mA and all Earthworks models draw 10 mA.

Comment: Thanks @Tony. I used TL072 or LM358 for op-amp stages with 9v batteries. I see that the LM321 works with 3.7v but I never used it. Would you have any suggestion for the low current op-amp?

Comment: Any CMOS Op Amp with that Vdd rating